# How to connect the inputstream to a sounpool or mediaplayer?

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, soundpool

Ok guys, it's me again. I'm trying to record internal audio playing from within the phone. I don't want to capture poor audio from the microphone, I would rather capture the audio from media player or soundpool. How do I connect the inputstream to a mediaplayer or sounpool? I would like to point out that I have multiple soundpools playing multiple samples so i would need to set the input stream to an array of soundpool objects or, i can set it to only one sound pool object and change the sound that is played through that object through an array. I say all that because it's a music app. say for instance there are 4 buttons with 4 separate music clips that play for 3 seconds a piece, how can i just play them for however long i want to and then i can save the finished product. so i would press startREC and then play the sounds playing though the one sound pool and then i can stop pause and wait for a second and then play some more buttons and stop the recording and i have a clean crisp non microphone recording. How can i do that?

```
public void newMETH() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://myradio,com/stream.mp3");
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd("sound.ogg");
    sp.load(afd, 1);
};
public void startREC() throws Exception {
    in = getAssets().open("aabbccdd.mp3");
    File outFolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/clxxxii");
    outFolder.mkdir();
    File outFile = new File(outFolder, "ooooooooohhhigetit.mp3");
    out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
};

public void stopREC() throws Exception {
    copyFile(in, out);
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**hi**

i think this can help you:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Audio_Recording_and_Playback_using_MediaPlayer_and_MediaRecorder

Comment: thank you , but that only allows me to record audio from a mic. I would rather record the system internal audio playing though the app.